# What factors can cause an Acoustic Model to fail?

Tags: speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I'm providing acoustic data to Microsoft's speech recognition service (cris.ai) which imports fine with no errors.  When the platform attempts to turn this into an Acoustic Model it fails (after about 30 mins) with no feedback.

Has anyone else had such an issue and managed to modify their training data to get this to succeed?

Comment: Same here, I gave up

Comment: There are many other toolkits to train the models and recognize speech.